# Different character encoding for some HTML elements

Tags: html

Is it possible to change the character encoding of one HTML element without changing the character encoding of the whole page? For example, I have this line:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Can I do this?

```
<span charset="windows-1252">Content here</span>
```

Comment: I would be astonished if that worked because the charset should correspond with the way the file itself was saved. Interesting question nevertheless.

Comment: [This article](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-html-encoding-declarations) has all you'd ever what to know about specifying character encodings in HTML.

Comment: @HereticMonkey yet it does not offer any answer to his question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. An HTML document as a whole has a character encoding. It is detected by browsers in a rather complicated manner, and this may involve reading an initial part of it using one encoding, then selecting another one after e.g. a suitable `meta` tag is encountered. But in that case the browser re-reads the document using the encoding so determined.

Answer (score 2):

While the HTML5 standard has a section named [`12.2.2.4 Changing the encoding while parsing`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#changing-the-encoding-while-parsing), this section specifies in a note this only happens with `<meta>` tags that changes encoding, which can only [appear once, in the first 1024 bytes of the document](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#charset).

So, it is not possible to change the encoding for a specific part of the HTML document.

Although not worded the same way, earlier versions of HTML, as well as XHTML, have the same kind of restrictions, preventing you from changing the encoding mid-document.